# Pdfpages: Hyperref always jumps to the first attachment

Tags: hyperref, koma-script, pdfpages

By using the package `pdfpages` I want to add attachments and drawings to my document. Just like a `ToC`, `LoF` and `LoT` there should be one list of attachements and one list of drawings. Furthermore I want to link to a specific attachment or drawing from out of the text with `\ref` or similar.

I already implemented all of this but there is a problem with the `hyperref` package:

If you click on an entry in the list of drawings or a respective `\ref`-link, the PDF will jump to that drawing – like you would expect. However, clicking on any entry from the list of attachments or a respective `\ref`-link will always lead you to the very first attachment. In other words:

click on drawing 001 -> drawing 001
click on drawing 002 -> drawing 002
click on drawing 003 -> drawing 003
but
click on attachment 001 -> attachment 001
click on attachment 002 -> attachment 001 (!!!)
click on attachment 003 -> attachment 001 (!!!)

Very strange: The document behaves vice versa if the order of the two `\DeclareNewTOC`-commands is changed. In other words:
click on drawing 001 -> drawing 001
click on drawing 002 -> drawing 001 (!!!)
click on drawing 003 -> drawing 001 (!!!)
but
click on attachment 001 -> attachment 001
click on attachment 002 -> attachment 002
click on attachment 003 -> attachment 003

Here is my MWE:
(please excuse the German comments...)

```
%Grundlegendes
\documentclass[a4paper,BCOR=10mm,DIV=12,headsepline,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}%10mm Bindekorrektur und 12er-Teilung; Damit entsteht ein linker Rand von 25mm bzw. 35mm (inkl. Bindekorrektur) und ein rechter Rand von 25 mm. Die Fläche für den Text ist 150mm breit.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{pdfpages}%Einbinden externer PDF-Dateien

%Querverweise und Metadaten:
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}%Pakete für "intelligente" Querverweise mit Seitenreferenz
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperfootnotes,linktoc=all,ngerman,raiselinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}%klickbare Verweise, Angabe von PDF-Metadaten
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}%"intelligente" Querverweise mit automatischem Typ

%neue Gleitumgebungen und Verzeichnisse
\newcommand*{\ausblenden}[1]{}          % wird gleich gebraucht, um die Eintragsnummern und Seitenzahlen auszublenden

\DeclareNewTOC[                         % Verzeichnis und Gleitumgebung für Anhänge
type=attachment,                        % Name der Umgebung
types=attachments,                      % Erweiterung (\listofattachments)
float,                                  % soll gleiten
floatpos=h,                             % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
name=Anhang,                            % Name in Überschriften
listname={Attachments},                     % Listenname
tocentryindent=0pt,                     % kein Einzug links
tocentrynumwidth=0pt,                   % keinen Platz für Eintragsnummern vorsehen
tocentryentrynumberformat=\ausblenden,  % Eintragsnummern ausblenden
% tocentrypagenumberformat=\ausblenden, % Seitenzahlen ausblenden
% tocentrylinefill=\hfill                   % Punkte ausblenden
]{loa}                                  % Dateiendung für dieses Verzeichnis (list of attachments)

\DeclareNewTOC[                         % Verzeichnis und Gleitumgebung für Zeichnungen
type=drawing,                           % Name der Umgebung
types=drawings,                         % Erweiterung (\listofdrawings)
float,                                  % soll gleiten
floatpos=h,                             % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
name=Zeichnung,                         % Name in Überschriften
listname={Drawings},                    % Listenname
tocentryindent=0pt,                     % kein Einzug links
tocentrynumwidth=0pt,                   % keinen Platz für Eintragsnummern vorsehen
tocentryentrynumberformat=\ausblenden,  % Eintragsnummern ausblenden
% tocentrypagenumberformat=\ausblenden, % Seitenzahlen ausblenden
% tocentrylinefill=\hfill                   % Punkte ausblenden
]{lod}                                  % Dateiendung für dieses Verzeichnis (list of drawings)

\begin{document}

\listofattachments
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listofdrawings
\endgroup

\newpage
%just some references for testing
\nameref{app:a001} and \nameref{app:a002}

\nameref{app:d001} and \nameref{app:d002}

\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}

\ohead{attachment 001}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,attachment,attachment 001,app:a001}]{dummy}
\ohead{attachment 002}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,attachment,attachment 002,app:a002}]{dummy}
\ohead{attachment 003}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,attachment,attachment 003,app:a003}]{dummy}

\ohead{drawing 001}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,drawing,drawing 001,app:d001}]{dummy}
\ohead{drawing 002}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,drawing,drawing 002,app:d002}]{dummy}
\ohead{drawing 003}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,drawing,drawing 003,app:d003}]{dummy}

\end{document}
```

Hopefully anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\DeclareNewToC` macros should be applied **before** `\usepackage{hyperref}` in order to get correct hyperlinks written the by the ToC - generation macros.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,BCOR=10mm,DIV=12,headsepline,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}%10mm Bindekorrektur und 12er-Teilung; Damit entsteht ein linker Rand von 25mm bzw. 35mm (inkl. Bindekorrektur) und ein rechter Rand von 25 mm. Die Fläche für den Text ist 150mm breit.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{pdfpages}%Einbinden externer PDF-Dateien

%Querverweise und Metadaten:
\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}%Pakete für "intelligente" Querverweise mit Seitenreferenz

%neue Gleitumgebungen und Verzeichnisse
\newcommand*{\ausblenden}[1]{}          % wird gleich gebraucht, um die Eintragsnummern und Seitenzahlen auszublenden

\DeclareNewTOC[                         % Verzeichnis und Gleitumgebung für Anhänge
type=attachment,                        % Name der Umgebung
types=attachments,                      % Erweiterung (\listofattachments)
float,                                  % soll gleiten
floatpos=h,                             % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
name=Anhang,                            % Name in Überschriften
listname={Attachments},                     % Listenname
tocentryindent=0pt,                     % kein Einzug links
tocentrynumwidth=0pt,                   % keinen Platz für Eintragsnummern vorsehen
tocentryentrynumberformat=\ausblenden,  % Eintragsnummern ausblenden
% tocentrypagenumberformat=\ausblenden, % Seitenzahlen ausblenden
% tocentrylinefill=\hfill                   % Punkte ausblenden
]{loa}                                  % Dateiendung für dieses Verzeichnis (list of attachments)

\DeclareNewTOC[                         % Verzeichnis und Gleitumgebung für Zeichnungen
type=drawing,                           % Name der Umgebung
types=drawings,                         % Erweiterung (\listofdrawings)
float,                                  % soll gleiten
floatpos=h,                             % voreingestellte Gleitparameter
name=Zeichnung,                         % Name in Überschriften
listname={Drawings},                    % Listenname
tocentryindent=0pt,                     % kein Einzug links
tocentrynumwidth=0pt,                   % keinen Platz für Eintragsnummern vorsehen
tocentryentrynumberformat=\ausblenden,  % Eintragsnummern ausblenden
% tocentrypagenumberformat=\ausblenden, % Seitenzahlen ausblenden
% tocentrylinefill=\hfill                   % Punkte ausblenden
]{lod}                                  % Dateiendung für dieses Verzeichnis (list of drawings)


\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperfootnotes,linktoc=all,ngerman,raiselinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}%klickbare Verweise, Angabe von PDF-Metadaten
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}%"intelligente" Querverweise mit automatischem Typ


\begin{document}

\listofattachments
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listofdrawings
\endgroup

\newpage
%just some references for testing
\nameref{app:a001} and \nameref{app:a002}

\nameref{app:d001} and \nameref{app:d002}

\includepdfset{pagecommand=\thispagestyle{scrheadings}}

\ohead{attachment 001}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,attachment,attachment 001,app:a001}]{dummy}
\ohead{attachment 002}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,attachment,attachment 002,app:a002}]{dummy}
\ohead{attachment 003}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,attachment,attachment 003,app:a003}]{dummy}

\ohead{drawing 001}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,drawing,drawing 001,app:d001}]{dummy}
\ohead{drawing 002}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,drawing,drawing 002,app:d002}]{dummy}
\ohead{drawing 003}
\includepdf[addtolist={1,drawing,drawing 003,app:d003}]{dummy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I never could find a \newcounter or \refstepcounter in KOMA to explain why is was working at all.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Perhaps it's some `\@definecounter`?

Comment: If option `float` is set, a counter named `<type>` will be defined.  So in the MWE the two counters `attachment` and `drawing` are defined. If option `type` is missing then the file extension would be used as name of the counter.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Your solution solved my problem. Thank you very much!